# Конкуренция знаков

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Допустимо ли использовать оба знака препинания в данной ситуации? Если да, то равноправны ли они?

> *Существуют две формы речи — устная и письменная.
>
> Существуют две
> формы речи: устная и письменная.*

1. Двоеточие после обобщающего слова.
2. Тире перед поясняющим членом предложения.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141716/discussion-on-question-by-ajgy--).

Comment: Количество способствует пояснению, и два элемента маловато для перечисления. 2:0 в пользу тире.

Comment: Главное вот что: двоеточие перед двумя элементами — это не норма (перед двумя вариантами в вопросе не в счёт, отдельное правило для этого есть). Раньше специально искал в справочниках Розенталя и Лопатина, чтобы подтвердить, и не нашёл ни одного примера.

Comment: @ oleed, на каком основании вы решаете, что норма,  а что — нет? С чего вы решили, что два элемента(как вы говорите), не повод для двоеточия?

Comment: @Серж Перечисление обычно используют, когда три и больше элемента. С двумя не всегда удачно. В примерах Розенталя и Лопатина два элемента всегда с тире. Это не зря так. С чем это связано? Перечислительная интонация не очень актуальна, когда особо нечего перечислять. Вот пример: *В саду растут такие деревья: персики и сливы.* Не маловато? Не лучше ли убрать перечисление и написать так? *В саду растут персики и сливы.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **5.** Если однородные члены предложения носят характер приложения или уточнения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия может ставиться **тире**: *Алый свет нежно заливал окрестности — ветряную **мельницу**, шиферные **крыши** машинно-тракторной станции, **элеваторы*** (Кат.); *Легенды и сказки любят все — **дети** и **взрослые**; Положительные черты характера проявляются всё равно в чём — **в сдержанности, в терпеливости, в смелости***...

[§ 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103) (Розенталь)

> Самые многочисленные случаи вариативности знаков препинания — параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире.
> **1.** После обобщающего слова перед перечислением однородных членов предложения часто ставится тире (вместо обычного двоеточия): ...*Что её больше волнует — **уход** мужа или **то**, что в глазах окружающих перестала существовать «образцовая семья»?* (Газ.)...

[§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания. Двоеточие — тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189) (Розенталь)

Так что допустимо использовать оба знака препинания — они равноправны (даже если имеется всего два однородных члена).

**Дополнение** (после комментариев)

*Количество способствует пояснению, и два элемента маловато для перечисления.*
*Где у Розенталя два элемента после двоеточия? Это не норма.*

Вот, норма ([Русский язык. Упражнения и комментарии](https://books.google.ee/books?id=cYuFAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=%D0%92%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8C:%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=d9oe7hejCl&sig=ACfU3U0n4gtSxtUzwuX10O-Cs0W6_tLWpg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd26e95qv8AhWElosKHS4CAn44ChDoAXoECBcQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8C%3A%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&f=falsehttps://books.google.ee/books?id=cYuFAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=%D0%92%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8C:%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=d9oe7hejCl&sig=ACfU3U0n4gtSxtUzwuX10O-Cs0W6_tLWpg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd26e95qv8AhWElosKHS4CAn44ChDoAXoECBcQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8C%3A%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&f=false)):

> [**340**] 1. В корзине была дичь: два тетерева и утка (Гонч). 2. Ничто не шевелилось: ни одна травка внизу, ни один лист на верхней ветви дерева (Т.)...
> [**341**] 8. И этим раскатистым, заливчатым «ха-ха-ха» завершилось все: и сватовство, и земное существование Беликова.

**Дополнение 2**
*Найдите с двумя равносильными предметами (без отрицания)...*
Из Нацкорпуса (["две формы"](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CjMKEdC00LLQtSDRhNC%2B0YDQvNGLKhcKCAgAEAoYMiAKIAAovubq4uLvzQtABTICCAE6AQEwAQ==)):
• Процветали только **две формы** общественного **питания:** ресторанная, но в ней недостаточно ярко были выдержаны социалистические принципы, и ― самые паршивые забегайловки, торгующие одной только водкой (Солженицын);
• ...существовали еще как минимум **две формы гоминидов:** одна в западной части материка, где на основании широко известных морфологических признаков она обозначена как неандертальская, и восточная, к которой относятся денисовцы (Деревянко, Шуньков);
• Необходимо отметить, что и при стремлении к власти, и при устремленности к собственно социальным достижениям возможны **две формы функционирования:** групповая и индивидуализированная (Фонарев);
• В этой борьбе столкнулись **две формы компетенции:** техническая и социальная (Шматко);
• Есть **две формы** морского **лука:** белая и красная (Алексеева).

**Дополнение 3** (последнее)

• Именительный падеж множественного числа слова *год* имеет две формы: года́ (мои года) и го́ды (Н. В. Соловьева. Словарь правильной русской речи).
•• Со студентами приходим к выводу, что в будущем времени причастия не могут употребляться, так как у причастия только две формы времени: настоящее и прошедшее (к.ф.н. Е. В. Чабристова).
••• Розенталь:
как правило, качественные прилагательные имеют две формы: полную (*красивый вид*) и краткую (*вид красив*);
возможны две формы сказуемого: постановка сказуемого в форме единственного числа и в форме множественного числа;
существуют две формы: *ноль* и *нуль*;
существуют две формы числительного: *ноль* и *нуль*;
литературный язык имеет две формы: устную и письменную, которые характеризуются своими особенностями.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141762/discussion-on-answer-by----).

Comment: @Серж Ну тогда ставьте двоеточие, когда один элемент, плюйте на количество, вообще его не учитывайте.

Comment: @Серж Чем больше элементов, тем актуальнее перечисление и двоеточие. С этим вы тоже не согласны? Это аксиома. Тоже нет логики? Вам просто надо её включить, если она у вас есть.

Comment: В словарях указано, что перечисление — действие по гл. *перечислить/перечислять*. Перечислить —считая кого-что-нибудь или составляя список кого-чего-нибудь, назвать, упомянуть всех или всё, **много кого-чего-нибудь**. Много — это три и больше. Двух обычно маловато, поэтому таких примеров мало (а в справочниках вообще нет). Чтобы понимать, удачно такое или нет, надо уметь чувствовать и анализировать язык. Перечисление подразумевает существенное количество.

Comment: Идём дальше. Из справочника Лопатина: Если обобщающее слово предшествует **ряду однородных членов**, то после обобщающего слова ставится двоеточие. Не маловато двух для ряда? Нормальным рядом считается 3 и больше (норма). То, что не норма, не всегда ошибка, но обычно оно неудачно.